# Bokeh custom action with custom icon

Tags: javascript, python, css, font-awesome, bokeh

I'm trying to build some custom actions to a bokeh plot inside the toolbar and for these custom actions I also need custom icons.

I've started from this [example](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/tool.html) which creates a drawing tool. It worked, everything's fine at this point.

For the custom icons, I started with this [example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/0.12.6/examples/custom/font-awesome) which creates a bokeh wrapper above fontawesome 4.6.3. Worked like a charm.

Now I wanted to combine these two, so first I made sure the fontawesome_icon.py wrapper is imported. Then the icon to be used for the draw tool must be set to the wrapped fontawesome icon, thus the icon of the DrawTool shall become 
`icon = "bk-u-fa bk-u-fa-pencil"`, because this is how the fontawesome icons are specified.

But this setup generates the following error in the browser on client side:

```
Error rendering Bokeh items: DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('bk-u-fa bk-u-fa-pencil') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.
    at e.t.render (http://localhost:5006/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=afab3eba5b3a72c05610143940e03c8e:31:460843)
    at e.render (http://localhost:5006/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=afab3eba5b3a72c05610143940e03c8e:31:517274)
    at e.t.initialize (http://localhost:5006/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=afab3eba5b3a72c05610143940e03c8e:31:460541)
    at e.t [as constructor] (http://localhost:5006/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=afab3eba5b3a72c05610143940e03c8e:31:93458)
    at e.t [as constructor] (http://localhost:5006/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=afab3eba5b3a72c05610143940e03c8e:31:16968)
    at e.t [as constructor] (http://localhost:5006/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=afab3eba5b3a72c05610143940e03c8e:31:460274)
    at new e (http://localhost:5006/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=afab3eba5b3a72c05610143940e03c8e:31:517173)
    at Object.i.build_views (http://localhost:5006/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=afab3eba5b3a72c05610143940e03c8e:31:13738)
    at t._build_tool_button_views (http://localhost:5006/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=afab3eba5b3a72c05610143940e03c8e:31:524696)
    at t.initialize (http://localhost:5006/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=afab3eba5b3a72c05610143940e03c8e:31:523943)
```

So obviously it doesn't like that I've given two classes in the same string as the icon.
I've tried several ways to specify both classes: `["bk-u-fa", "bk-u-fa-power-off"]`, `"bk-u-fa"; "bk-u-fa-power-off"`, `"bk-u-fa" "bk-u-fa-power-off"`, `"bk-u-fa", "bk-u-fa-power-off"` but none of them worked.

So the question is if there is a another way the custom action with the custom icon can be achieved? 
Or how is it possible to specify more than one css class to such a custom action icon? Or maybe the first class could be specified as the icon string and the other part as some custom css class?

Below you can find my main app, called mygestures.py, you just need to copy this file int the fontawesome [example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/0.12.6/examples/custom/font-awesome) and start it with `bokeh serve --show mygestures.py`. It has a button which appends at the bottom some text and an icon, to make sure the icons are working.

```
from bokeh.core.properties import Instance
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Tool
from bokeh.util.compiler import TypeScript
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models import Button
from bokeh.models import CustomJS

from fontawesome_icon import FontAwesomeIcon


TS_CODE = """
import {GestureTool, GestureToolView} from "models/tools/gestures/gesture_tool"
import {ColumnDataSource} from "models/sources/column_data_source"
import {GestureEvent} from "core/ui_events"
import * as p from "core/properties"

export class DrawToolView extends GestureToolView {
  model: DrawTool

  //this is executed when the pan/drag event starts
  _pan_start(_ev: GestureEvent): void {
    this.model.source.data = {x: [], y: []}
  }

  //this is executed on subsequent mouse/touch moves
  _pan(ev: GestureEvent): void {
    const {frame} = this.plot_view

    const {sx, sy} = ev
    if (!frame.bbox.contains(sx, sy))
      return

    const x = frame.xscales.default.invert(sx)
    const y = frame.yscales.default.invert(sy)

    const {source} = this.model
    source.get_array("x").push(x)
    source.get_array("y").push(y)
    source.change.emit()
  }

  // this is executed then the pan/drag ends
  _pan_end(_ev: GestureEvent): void {}
}

export namespace DrawTool {
  export type Attrs = p.AttrsOf<Props>

  export type Props = GestureTool.Props & {
    source: p.Property<ColumnDataSource>
  }
}

export interface DrawTool extends DrawTool.Attrs {}

export class DrawTool extends GestureTool {
  properties: DrawTool.Props

  constructor(attrs?: Partial<DrawTool.Attrs>) {
    super(attrs)
  }

  tool_name = "Drag Span"
  icon = "bk-u-fa bk-u-fa-pencil"
  event_type = "pan" as "pan"
  default_order = 12

  static initClass(): void {
    this.prototype.type = "DrawTool"
    this.prototype.default_view = DrawToolView

    this.define<DrawTool.Props>({
      source: [ p.Instance ],
    })
  }
}
DrawTool.initClass()
"""


class DrawTool(Tool):
    __implementation__ = TypeScript(TS_CODE)
    source = Instance(ColumnDataSource)


source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[]))

plot = figure(x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10), tools=[DrawTool(source=source)])
plot.title.text = "Drag to draw on the plot"
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source)

# show(plot)

button = Button(label="Press Me", callback=CustomJS(
    code="""
    console.log("button callback"); 

    btn = document.createElement("div"); 
    btn.innerHTML = "<h1><i class=\\"bk-u-fa bk-u-fa-pencil\\"></i> Icon and some text</h1>";
    document.getElementsByClassName("bk-root")[0].appendChild(btn);

    """
))

plot = figure(x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10), tools=[DrawTool(source=source)])
plot.title.text = "Drag to draw on the plot"
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source)

curdoc().add_root(column(row(button), row(plot)))
```

Thanks for your help,
Gabor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or how is it possible to specify more than one css class to such a custom action icon?

It's not possible, currently. The built-in [`ButtonToolButtonView` code](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/f5eea9d475a08dc7105bf27cb62558f7bd4f6f44/bokehjs/src/lib/models/tools/button_tool.ts#L23-L33) does this:

```js
render(): void {
  empty(this.el)
  const icon = this.model.computed_icon
  if (isString(icon)) {
    if (startsWith(icon, "data:image"))
      this.el.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + icon + "')"
    else
      this.el.classList.add(icon)
  }
  this.el.title = this.model.tooltip
}
```

The second codepath was really only developed with the built-in toolbar icons in mind, and only ever adds a single CSS class. The first codepath, which handles images encoded as data-urls, is what we added to afford some possibility for custom icons. So that is what I would recommend: encode the icon you want to display as a base64 data-url and set `icon` with that string.

Alternatively, you are looking at:

- making a custom extensions that subclass `ButtonTool` to accept more than one CSS class
- make a feature request on GH to have this added as a feature

The first is much more work, and the second will take much more time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess it would work if I would use an icon pack that defines only one class for its icons, right? Would it work if I would deploy the server in a directory format and the css would be imported statically: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#directory-format. So instead of making a bokeh wrapper over the iconpack, like in the case of fontawesome, I could use direclty the name of the icon, since the corresponding css is loaded.

Comment: That certainly sounds reasonable and plausible, but I have never tried it personally.

Comment: Thanks, it worked indeed, I'll post the code as an answer, so others may have it:) Another question would be if do you know whether it is possible or not to trigger an action in the bokeh python backend from a custom tool. I know the predefined tools are triggering some event (like pan, zoom, etc) which can have a callback in the backed, and I also know that these are hardcoded and no such event can be generated from custom tools, but is there a way to trigger some action in the backend from the custom tool's js callback?

Comment: Just for the sake of information organization and accessibility, please ask separate questions as separate questions, either here, or on the project Discourse https://discourse.bokeh.org/c/community-support